# javascript - Why does this canvas image not rotate correctly?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Why does this canvas image not rotate correctly?

When I click the rotate button the image rotates but gets cropped weirdly. I want the image to stay intact and simply rotate.

Important: I'm not looking to rotate the div, I'm looking to rotate the actual image.

See fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8V4V7/2/

Code:

```
function rotateBase64Image(base64data, callback) {
   console.log("what we get: " + base64data);

    var canvas = document.getElementById("dummyCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = base64data;
    image.onload = function() {
        ctx.translate(image.width, image.height);
        ctx.rotate(Math.PI);
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        callback(canvas.toDataURL());
    };
}
```

**EDIT:**
I need the image to rotate by 90 degrees on every click.

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
ctx.rotate(Math.PI/2);
```

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask if my code don't make sense or doesn't work as you wanted it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me (I specified the height and width of the canvas inside the `onload` function):

```
function rotateBase64Image(base64data, callback) {
    console.log("what we get: " + base64data);

    var canvas = document.getElementById("dummyCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = base64data;
    image.onload = function () {

        canvas.height = image.height;
        canvas.width = image.width;

        ctx.translate(image.width, image.height);
        ctx.rotate(Math.PI);
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        callback(canvas.toDataURL());
    };
}
```

## Edit

**Updated function to rotate 90 degrees with every click (remove `i` in `i*Math.PI` to rotate 90 degrees only once)**

```
var i = 0;
function rotateBase64Image(base64data, callback) {
   console.log("what we get: " + base64data);

    var canvas = document.getElementById("dummyCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = base64data;
    image.onload = function() {
        canvas.width = image.height;
        canvas.height = image.width;

       ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
       i++;
       ctx.rotate(i*Math.PI/2);
       ctx.translate(-canvas.width / 2, -canvas.height / 2);

        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

    };
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8V4V7/8/)

Comment: @user13500 yeah, I hesitated and wanted to try it on a jsFiddle. You can see I had the same code from the whole beginning.

Comment: @DanielLisik this works, thanks. can you please make it rotate by 90 deg instead of 180? then its yours.

Comment: @quelquecosa you got it. Wait a few mins, please.

Comment: Bonus: @DanielLisik can you please explain why this is necessary? for example, "because every canvas must always have a set width and height"

Comment: @quelquecosa see updated answer. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @DanielLisik  Since you're rotating the image by 90 degrees you might want to set canvas.width=image.height and canvas.height=image.width so if the image is not square it will not get clipped when rotated.  Also you "should" wrap code that involved transformations (like translate, rotate) inside context.save and context.restore.  That way your transformations won't accidentally "bleed" into your next drawings.

Comment: @quelquecosa I must admit I'm no guru in Canvas, but what I *do* know is that when you call the `translate` function, you change the `0,0` coordinates to the values you pass to the function. Thus you need to specify the width and height of the canvas for the image whole image to fit.

Comment: @markE okay, didn't know about `save` and `restore`. Need to dive into it. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @quelquecosa did you wan't the image to rotate 90 degrees with every click or just once?

Comment: @DanielLisik with every click, 90 deg clockwise

Comment: @quelquecosa ok, then my current updated code is what you want.

Comment: @markE: If one set width and / or height one issue a hard reset of the canvas. Translate etc. + old paint is gone. No need nor use in save / restore.

Comment: @user13500  True--but not my point!  In the simple case where you are only rotating the image then flipping the canvas width/height for the next 90 degree rotation will nicely reset the context state.  But if you are doing subsequent draws before again changing the width/height then it's good programming practice to reset the context state.  :)

Comment: @markE: Indeed. Believe I misread your comment (Or my head was somewhere else). Believe I somehow interpret you as saying he should save before setting width/height and restoring after painting ...

Answer (score 0):

Just some supporting info for rotations, notably the saving of the context and how to rotate around the center of the image.

```
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
//save the context
//pushes a Matrix on the transformation stack
context.save();
context.translate(x, y); //where to put image
context.rotate(angle); //angle in degrees (i think...)
context.scale(scale); //optional scale
//rotate around center of image
context.drawImage(bitmap, -image.width / 2, -image.height / 2);
//or rotate around top left corner of image
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
//restore the canvas
//pop a matrix off the transformation stack
context.restore();
```

References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Transformations

http://html5.litten.com/understanding-save-and-restore-for-the-canvas-context/